# Trying to connect Excel 2013 with Oracle - ORA-12154

Tags: oracle, database-connection, excel-2013

I am trying to connect into Oracle through `Power Query > From Database > From Oracle Database` and then I type `BI_TST`, which is within my TNSNAMES (located in: `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\network\ADMIN`), and has the connection below inside:

```
BI_TST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = srv-oracle3.mycompany.com.br)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = bitst)
    )
  )
```

Also i have the variable path configured as `TNS_ADMIN=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\network\ADMIN`.

When I use SQL Developer to connect, not using TNS put setting all the information manually, it works!

When I try to connect using TNS within Excel I get the error:

```
Message=ORA-12154: TNS:não foi possível resolver o identificador de conexão especificado

    ErrorCode=-2146232008
```

Wich means in English: "could not resolve the connect identifier"

Could anyone please help me in this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I've had my fill of tnsnames.  I understand the idea behind it and can appreciate that, but I spend more time figuring out why it's not working than I do saving the extra keystrokes.

In my opinon, just bypass TNSnames use Oracle's ezconnect:

```
srv-oracle3.mycompany.com.br:1521/bitst
```

In place of:

```
BI_TST
```

This should work for ODBC as well.  If you can't direct connect through PowerQuery's Oracle driver, try going through ODBC.  While it's an additional layer you probably don't want, I doubt you'll notice a performance difference, and it may abstract the difficulties you normally have to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. O googled for this ezconnect thing but didn't figure out where to put it. Should this be put anywhere in my TNS File? I am also trying to do it throught ODBC but it requests me to specify a TNS name.

Comment: Yeah, where it says "Service Name" or "TNS Service" or something like that, just put your EZ Connect string.  Oracle will do the rest for you.  If your tnsnames sample was correct, the string I have listed should actually work fine.  From time to time you have to do a little but of discovery on the service name, but it usually works as-is.  When you do this, you won't need the TNS names file at all, at least not for this connection.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify Hambone's response, to connect Excel to Oracle via Oracle client driver without using TNS Names:

1. Go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > ODBC Data Sources
2. Go to File DSN tab
3. Choose Oracle driver (e.g. Oracle11gr1)
4. Provide a name for the new data source (any name)
5. When prompted for Service Name, enter host:port/servicename e.g. db123:1521/service123

Hope this works for everyone.